# How to set a variable equal to the contents of another variable?

Tags: variables, batch-file, variable-assignment

In the following (simplified example) batch file I am having difficulty correctly setting `Y`:

```
@Echo off
setlocalenabledelayed Expansion
set EqS=Nope
set X=Eq
set Y=%X%S 
echo Y
```

How can I get the output of this script to be `Nope` instead of `EqS`?

Comment: Do you mean you want `Y` to be a pointer to `EqS` or you want `Y` to contain the string "EqS" or you want `Y` to have the same value as `EqS`?

Comment: This currently will echo EqS for me. What I want it to echo is Nope.

Comment: Currently your script will echo `Y` for you, for `Nope` you can use `%Y2%` of my answer

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt: OP's question is very clear: he wants to know how the last `echo` command show `Nope`. In my opinion, your questions just confuse him instead of help him...

Comment: @Aacini, I asked the question before the edit.  It was pretty ambiguous before.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt: I see that now, you are right...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Karl ask, there could be different meanings of your question.
I try to give an answer for each possibility

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set EqS=Nope
set X=Eq

REM set Y1 to "EqS" 
set Y1=%X%S 

REM set Y2 to "Nope" (content of EqS)
set Y2=!%X%S!

REM set Y3 to "!EqS!"
set Y3=^^!%X%S^^!

echo %Y1%
echo %Y2%
echo %Y3%
set EqS=Something
echo(
echo Text %Y1%
echo Content %Y2%
echo Pointer %Y3%
```