# Setting variables with variables - Batch

Tags: batch-file

So I've just about finished a really complicated batch file (first big one I've wrote) and i'm stuck at the last part. The program needs variables to be generated as the user needs them. I figured that part out, but now i'm having trouble calling them.
This is what i have (sorry its easier to show you than explain)

```
set /A mquanto=%mquant%
:varmakerstart
set /p compname=Machine Number:
echo set /A comp%mquanto%=\\LAB-%compname%
set /A mquanto=%mquanto%-1
if %mquanto% lss 1 goto startloop
goto varmakerstart
:startloop
set /A mquanto=%mquant%
:loop
set /A tcomp=
```

What i need is a way to set one of the variables created in the 4th line to the variable tcomp, and i can't have more or less variables than the value of mquant. I'm sorry about any vagueness and i will try to explain any thing that is needed.

Comment: I dind't understand what you are trying, but perhaps this could help [How to set a variable equal to the contents of another variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363019/how-to-set-a-variable-equal-to-the-contents-of-another-variable). You could show what do you expect in which variable (you could add some pseudo code)

Comment: I'm naming a variable with another variable so when the user enters input (lets assume mquanto equals 5) it creates the variable comp5 (with the users input) and than creates comp4 (it loops until it reaches comp1) etc. But the problem i'm having is that mquanto is user defined so i don't know its value at the start of the program (so i don't know how many variables it will output) and i need to be able to set tcomp to any of those variables so what i was thinking was something along the lines of adding this next line at the end
    set /A tcomp=comp%mquanto%
but that sets the value to comp5

Comment: instead of the actual value of the variable comp5

Answer (score 0):

if your going to set a variable to equal another then this is an easy solution....

```
set a=
set b=1
set /p a=?:
if %a%==%b% goto :NEXT

:NEXT

you have entered the correct number! The number was %b%.
ping localhost -n 3 >nul
```

I hope this helps a bit!